Question about how force is distributed based on initial hitting angle in multiple pool balls
Suppose you have a standard triangle rack of billiard balls under ideal conditions (all balls are touching and identical, no friction, and all elastic collisions, ect). Suppose force F is applied to the top of the triangle (just like in most normal matches of pool), at some angle.
How exactly is the force distributed then amongst the balls? If the force were to be perpendicular, I assume that the force is evenly distributed amongst each point of contact, so each ball has equal velocity in the second layer of 2 balls. However, how does this generalize for all angles?
It seems that no matter how the first ball is hit, the points of contact between the first ball and second ball remain the same (at 30 degrees relative to the perpendicular angle), and thus the direction of the force remains at 30 degrees. I vaguely know the assumption that when a ball hit another, the ball goes perpendicular to the point of contact of the hit, explaining why the balls in the last line always go at 30 degrees.
But from this, I feel as though this slightly contradicts the asymmetrical force distribution seen. If the direction of the force is always converted to 30 degrees regardless of the initial direction, then why is the force distributed at differing points accounting for direction (as in, suppose an angled shot has a y-component to it as well. Under this assumption, wouldn't the y-component get converted along with the x-component into a completely unrelated angle upon the second layer of collision? How come there being a y-component seems to "favor" the force distributions?)
Another related question is how exactly is force "distributed"? I would greatly appreciate resources or an explanation as to how energy is distributed between balls touching multiple points. For example, the first ball is touching the two balls on the row below, and when the force is applied, it would then "bounce" back. But in what proportion? Would it be 1/3 of F as it has two points of contact with the other balls? How would this work during energy transfer in the third layer, where the middle ball has two points of contact, while the side balls only have 1? I notice that the y-components of the middle ball cancel out into a lesser y-component. How would conservation of momentum work in this case?
In online simulators, it seems the white cue ball "bounces off" the stationary ball when they hit. However, when the force is propagated through the triangle, you technically have balls with force at the front, applying force to the stationary balls at the back of the triangle just like the white ball. However, this does not result in a "bouncing" pattern to happen, rather the balls in the triangle all go the same direction. Is there any explanation as to why this doesn't occur when balls are touching?
I would appreciate if you guys can provide some calculations or formulas as to proving these types of problems, or possibly essays/articles/papers specifically on this topic.
Sorry if this is a basic question, I am in high school, and I only learned of one dimensional collisions in physics a while ago, while I am doing this for a (honestly poorly chosen) topic for a math unit on vectors.

Momentum is conserved in all collisions, both in the "x" and "y" directions.  This means that how the force is "distributed" is probably not a relevant question.
